# Python, посоветуйте литературу

Tags: python, веб-программирование, книги

Посоветуйте хорошую литературу по Питону, направленную на создание Веб-приложений. И посоветуйте среду разработки в которой стоит работать, или там без компиляции? И много ли хостингов поддерживают Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из книг:

- Марк Лутц изучаем Python 4е издание.. (самое лучшее что я видел / 1272 стр).
- А.Головатый Django подробное руководство 2е издание (можно скачать в сети / 550 стр).

хостинг с django:

- [Установка и настройка Apache, mod_wsgi, Django, MySQL в Debian / Ubuntu](http://debianworld.ru/articles/ustanovka-i-nastrojka-apache-mod_wsgi-django-mysql-v-debian-ubuntu/)
- [jino.ru](http://www.jino.ru/services/hosting_django.html) сам не тестировал из-за катастрофической нехватки времени
  [image]

Python IDE:

- PyCharm отличная среда для python в том числе заточено под django и поддерживает что-то там от google ( точно не скажу ибо не заинтересован в google примочках)
- Eclipce с плагином для python не плохая IDE, но мне не понравилось..
- любой текстовый редактор с поддержкой utf-8 кодировки

  *а вообще эти вопросы уже тысячи раз обсуждены на каждом форуме пользуйтесь поиском ребят!*

Comment: Спасибо,а что никто на чистом Питоне не пишет веб-приложения? Только через Джанго? Я просто не люблю фреймворки... С ними опыт будет плохо идти

Comment: чистый python под web это cgi: нечитаемо, убогосопроваждаемо и еще куча минусов...  
хотите опыт на python пишите UI и решайте всякие интересные задачки.. скил под web отличается от скила под состему только названием библиотек и способами вывода информации, базовые скилы языка одинаково применяются во всех его проявлениях

Answer (score 2):

Г. Россум, Ф.Л.Дж. Дрейк, Д.С. Откидач
Язык программирования Python

Среда разработки: Sublime Text 2

Framework: Django :)

Вменяемого хостинга мало.
Чистый Python без проблем, Django с трудом.

Comment: Спасибо, фреймворками всё равно не пользуюсь)

Comment: Я тоже не пользовался, пока не увидел Django.
Но вообще вполне разумный баланс между «мясным фреймворком» и «голым python» мне видится Google App Engine. С одной стороны есть ORM (BigTable опять же), а с другой — полная свобода в остальном :)